# Renamed visual studio project, error when publishing (ResolveAssemblyReference.cache)

Tags: visual-studio, build, publish

My solution contains two projects. Both have been renamed from 'LearnUmbraco.***' to 'OnceUpon.**'

The solution builds fine, however when trying to publish via FTP, the error occurs:

```
Error Copying file obj\Debug\LearnUmbraco.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\LearnUmbraco.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache failed. Could not find file 'obj\Debug\LearnUmbraco.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache'.     0   0   OnceUpon.WebUI
```

If I look in my obj/Debug folder i do indeed have a ResolveAssemblyReference.cache however it is obviously prefixed with ;OnceUpon.**.'.

Where/how is this file generated. I'd like to change the configuration so it looks for the renamed version.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Close the solution and open the csproj file. The old references were still in there.